# How do I start a tab as a different user from a predefined task?

Tags: powershell, conemu

I'm trying to create a saved task that will start a powershell console in ConEmu as a different user. This is the closest I've gotten. It launches the prompt for password inside ConEmu, but then opens powershell in a new window outside of ConEmu.

```
"runas /user:domain\otheruser "%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit"" "-cur_console:n:t:PS-otheruser"
```

Comment: Wondering, why not to read ConEmu's [wiki]( http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/NewConsole) about -cur_console:u:user:pwd parameter?

Comment: You're right! I totally didn't see it there. I saw that runas was the a option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works just fine:

```
"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -cur_console:n:u:domain\otheruser:pwd
```